# Can I run a cmd command in particular directory I want, with python script

Tags: python

I want to create such script by which I can select directory from my pc and run any kind of cmd command there.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
import os

path = "path to your dir"
os.chdir(path)
os.system("ls -la")
```

or you can use the subprocess module (as the official docs recommend):

```
import os
import subprocess

path = "path to your dir"
os.chdir(path)

subprocess.run(["ls", "-la"])
```

for python versions before 3.5, you must use `call`:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-la"])
```